# Expressing the combination of four transformations?

Tags: geometry, transformation, invariance

Consider a transformation $(x, t)\mapsto (x',t') = \left(x^{k}, t^{\frac{1}{k}}\right)$ with $k=e^{\Delta b}.$ The metric it preserves is just that points stay on certain curves. These curves are given by:
$$
t=\exp\left(\frac{n}{\log x}\right)
$$

So $$n=\log(x)\log(t)$$ is a preserved quantity of the transformation.

Consider three more preserved quantities of similar transformations: $$n=\log(1-x)\log(t) $$

$$ n=\log(x)\log(1-t) $$

$$ n=\log(1-x)\log(1-t)  $$

> How does one express the combination of all four transformations?

I think it has to do with composition but I can't see how to fit everything together in a way that makes sense. I am trying to describe the combination of the four transformations happening simultaneously so I don't see how composition will work.